# How to handle custom exceptions using i18 message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, java-8

I have written a spring boot application with custom exceptions. Everything is working well. However, I am quite new to localization. I like to add german language for Postman headers; from--> "You did not do anything to have a plane" to--> "Sie haben nichts getan, um ein Flugzeug zu haben", my working code below;

```
My customException below;

public class PlaneTypeNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4314211343358454345L;

    public PlaneTypeNotFoundException () {

        super("You did not do anything to have a plane");
    }

}
```

My ExceptionResponse below;

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExceptionResponse {

    private LocalDateTime date;
    private String message;
}
```

My Exception Handler Class below;

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class PlaneTypeExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(PlaneTypeNotFoundException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handlePlaneTypeNotFoundException(PlaneTypeNotFoundException ex,
            WebRequest request) {
        log.debug("PlaneType Not Found --> {}", ex.getMessage(), request);
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(LocalDateTime.now(), ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
        protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        log.debug("The request Parameteres whic you are sending is wrong", ex.getMessage(), request);

    Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    body.put("date", LocalDate.now());
    body.put("status", status.value());

    List<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream().map(x -> x.getDefaultMessage())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    body.put("errors", errors);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

My LocaleResolver class below;

```
public class SmartLocaleResolver extends CookieLocaleResolver {

    @Override
    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String acceptLanguage = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        if (acceptLanguage == null || acceptLanguage.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return super.determineDefaultLocale(request);
        }
        return request.getLocale();
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasenames("i18n/messages");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new SmartLocaleResolver();
    }
}
```

also, in resources I have created a folder called 'i18n' moreover, created two files with a named'messages_en.properties','messages.de'. But, I have no clue what to I have to write inside this file . is it something like .. plane.type.not.found = you did not do anything to have a plane and also how to pass my locale custom resolver to controlleradvice which is PlaneTypeExceptionHandler to be able to convert from english to german for postman calls.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write messages in properties as a key value pair.

### messages_en.properties

plane_msg = "You did not do anything to have a plane"

### messages.de.properties

plane_msg = "Sie haben nichts getan, um ein Flugzeug zu habe"

Comment: Thank you for your answer only question is what should ı do myControllerAdvice, what to write there?